# Where to find Request_Cancelled detail in HTTPERR Log

Tags: .net, iis

I have a webapi service in iis.when i use Httpclient to access it,i get timeout sometimes.I find Request_Cancelled Error in HTTPERR Log.I googled it for a long time,but still cant find anything about **Request_Cancelled**.
Below is one information of this error.

```
2020-06-30 09:15:25 * 27412 * 8080 HTTP/1.1 POST * - - 2 Request_Cancelled *
```

Anbody can help me?Can i get detail informations  of this error through some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If the timeout in your Httpclient is greater than the timeout in the service, the error Request_Cancelled will appear.

You can try to set the timeout in your Httpclient smaller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I saw my HttpClient set the timeout is two minutes which is equal with the default timeout in the service.I will reduce the timeout value in my httclient,but why this problem just happens occasionally，and why this occurs when request time is less than the timeout i set.

Comment: Your question now is that this error sometimes occurs?

Comment: I think I got the bug which is from redis access library.i use stackexchange.redis library,when is high concurrency ,stackexchange.redis will connect to redis very slowly,even throw an unavaliable connect.i change the anther library now,but i got below error ``only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted``

Comment: You can try the following steps to solve this error. 1.opened CMD and typed in : netstat -a. 2.take a look in the Local Address column. 3.take a look at the port portion. 4.check the port in your program is already active in another program. 5.if so, change your port in your program to something else.

Comment: Thank you ,i got the solution by singleton redis connection class finally